# Error when adding content to page in 2sxc content type/view

Tags: 2sxc, dotnetnuke

I have problem with the 2sxc content apps. no problem with the install but when i choose an content type i get this error:

```
Error: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot convert null to 'bool' because it is a non-nullable value type at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object ) at ASP._Page_Portals_0_2sxc_Content_Image__ImageImagelist_cshtml.Execute() in I:\wwwroot\dnndev.me_980\Portals\0\2sxc\Content\Image\_ImageImagelist.cshtml:line 28 at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c__DisplayClass7.<RenderPageCore>b__6(TextWriter writer) at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) at ASP._Page_Portals_0_2sxc_Content_Image__Max_1_cshtml.Execute() in I:\wwwroot\dnndev.me_980\Portals\0\2sxc\Content\Image\_Max 1.cshtml:line 12 at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) at ToSic.Sxc.Engines.RazorEngine.Render(TextWriter writer) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Razor\Engines\Razor\RazorEngine.cs:line 67 at ToSic.Sxc.Engines.RazorEngine.RenderTemplate() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Razor\Engines\Razor\RazorEngine.cs:line 77 at ToSic.Sxc.Engines.EngineBase.Render() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc\Engines\EngineBase.cs:line 148 at ToSic.Sxc.Blocks.BlockBuilder.Render() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc\Blocks\BlockBuilder_Render.cs:line 57
```

I read something that there may be a problem with the demo content like the pictures .. but I do not know, I just get this error..

Please help me.
this content manager may be exactly what i need in my dnn project
(running on dnn 9.8.0 and 2sxc content v11.10.1)

Comment: Are you in a situation where you could rollback to before you installed 2sxc? Try installing 2sxc 11.7.3 (LTS) instead. It will be helpful to know if you get no error, the same error, or a different error.

Also, can you describe what steps you used to deploy the Content App? And do you know what version of the Content App you installed? 11.0.5 or 11.0.3 or??

Comment: There was no difference when I installed v 11.7.3. I get the same error. i hav also tried v11.5.1 same error.. but its only the views with an image. the other once works fine.

Comment: Are you familiar with how the View's Presentation settings get mapped and handled? It looks like line 26-28 in this file (link below) are throwing convert error. So for whatever reason, there is .Presentation is null. It shouldn't be. If you know C# you could update the code to handle the null. Or you could figure out why Presentation is not set and just fix that. It might be as simple as the View's Presentation is set, but there is no Demo item set? Or that the assigned Demo item was deleted?

https://github.com/2sic/2sxc-content-app/blob/master/Image/_ImageImagelist.cshtml#L26

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what issue you ran into, but please be aware of the fact that there are 2 editions of the code - one for BS3 and one for BS4. It could be that your skin is BS3 and that code is probably not maintained as well, since it's rarely used nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the cause. IsPublished seems to return Null instead of true/false in the newer 2sxc versions. Will fix asap, 11.11.03 will have a fix in a few hours.

https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/2300